# Is it possible to implement custom transport agent to update the email in Office365?

Tags: office365, exchange-transport-agents

We can implement our own custom transport agent to update email in on-prem Exchange servers.

Can we do the same with Office365 as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own custom transport provider for any purpose, see [MAPI Service Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-service-providers) for more information.

Comment: Need to construct Custom transport agent for O365.